# Solr admin shows nothing (nutch)

Tags: solr, indexing, nutch, luke

I've successfully created a Solr index crawling a few pages using nutch. Querying the index using Luke I get the expected results (default field 'content'). However, when I try using the solr/admin interface I get everything using q=*:* as expected:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="start">0</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="version">2.2</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="11" start="0">
  <doc>
    <float name="boost">1.0</float>
    <str name="content">
      'a lot of text...'
    </str>
    <str name="digest">f73dc90d5ab992f62ba3980de2312dfe</str>
    <str name="id">http://thenet.net/</str>
    <str name="segment">20120529084510</str>
    <str name="title">1 < 2 < 3</str>
    <date name="tstamp">2012-05-29T06:45:12.872Z</date>
    <str name="url">http://theurl.net</str>
  </doc>
```

but absolutely nothing when querying for specific strings:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">java</str>
      <str name="version">2.2</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

At the Solr admin interface it says:

```
mro:8983
cwd=/$PATH_TO_SOLR_AND_NUTH_DIRS/solr/example SolrHome=solr/./ 
HTTP caching is OFF
```

In schema.xml 'content' is default search field.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fieldType for your content field in your schema.xml file. If it is set to `string` then that would explain why you are not getting any query results for specific text values. You should use a fieldType of `text_general` or something similar to get better search results as that fieldType will tokenize, filter and stem the values that are indexed. Please reference [Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Token Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) for more information.